# Google rich snippets code div

Tags: html, rich-snippets

I checked many different sites (official one also) and all the examples display the google snippets code itemscope/itemtype inside a div and the itemprop inside a span.
I'm wondering if this is just a simple way to show samples code or is the only way yo display it.

I have my address in a list so i wrote like this:

```
                <li itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i> <p class="labelSocial">Address:</p>
                    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Glogauer+Stra%C3%9Fe+21/@52.49226,13.4369,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47a84fb24234006b:0x36dfe942fb2b5f97" target="_blank">
                    <p class="addressText"> 
                        <span itemprop="streetAddress"> Glougauerstrasse 21, </span> </br> 
                        <span itemprop="postalCode"> 12435 </span> 
                        <span itemprop="addressLocality"> - Berlin </span> 
                        <span itemprop="addressCountry"> (DE) </span> 

                    </p></a>   
                </li>
```

is that also correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is fine but you'll have to nest schema.org/PostalAddress under some main category but use of `<li>` tag is correct. Here is what Google Structured Data testing tools shows  for the code you mentioned above-

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:800501214b811a6b2bbfb52e2d77f96d

In order to tell Google and other search engines that address is related to what, we must specify a category and nest postal address inside it. Please see the example, schema.org/PostalAdsress is nested inside LocalBusiness schema:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <h1><span itemprop="name">Beachwalk Beachwear & Giftware</span></h1>
  <span itemprop="description"> A superb collection of fine gifts and clothing
  to accent your stay in Mexico Beach.</span>
  <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">3102 Highway 98</span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Mexico Beach</span>,
    <span itemprop="addressRegion">FL</span>
  </div>
  Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">850-648-4200</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the checking! What you mean nest under main category, which categories for example?

Comment: I have added the explanation in my answer, kindly check.